# How much ram required for 138 gb database

Tags: mysql, sql

How much ram required for 138GB database

My server has 8GB ram

```sql
SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=130971520000;
```

Using query like:

```sql
select count(*) from log;
```

Database error is :
`ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Comment: Your value is way to hight, from the mysql [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) "On a dedicated database server, you might set the buffer pool size to 80% of the machine's physical memory size" So if mysql is the only thing that is running on that server the maximum you should set it to is ~ 6GB.

Comment: And if you lose your connection, it is because of the timeout, usually set to 600 seconds. If your query takes too much time, you will get timeout

Comment: even after change ram 32gb still  showing  hanging query

Comment: select table_schema "DB name (table_schema)",
    -> sum((data_length+index_length)/1024/1024/1024) AS "DB size in GB" from
    -> information_schema.tables group by table_schema;

Comment: +------------------------+------------------+
| DB name (table_schema) | DB size in GB    |
+------------------------+------------------+
| information_schema     |   0.000152587890 |
| logs                   | 138.609375000000 |
| mysql                  |   0.002430885097 |
| performance_schema     |   0.000000000000 |
| radius                 |   4.291687011718 |
| sys                    |   0.000015258789 |
| test                   |   0.000015258789 |
+------------------------+------------------+

Comment: log database size 138 gb

Comment: The minimum amount of memory depends on your performance expectations, the nature of the data, and the nature of queries.  Inserts into one massive table with no indexes is going to be quite different from maintaining a database with lots of transactions and lots of triggers and that in turn will be different from complex SQL needed for analytics.

Comment: @VivekSrivastava SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=20*1024*1024*1024; for size of 20 GB, now that you have 32GB of ram. System will just take a while to count all the ROWS from the table you are interested in.